# WPF. Bind to height of cell in GridViewColumn?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, gridview, datagridviewcolumn

I've a GridView defined like this:

```
            <ListView x:Name="colorLegend" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding /Colors}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Image" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Background="{Binding Brush}" Height="20" Width="40" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="auto" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I want the height of the border inside the first cell to be as high as the height of the cell column. 
Can I bind the height of the border to the height of the second cell?

What I want is to be able to change the fontsize for the second cell and the border in first to resize to match the change?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate using some snapshot as in what is desired? You `Border`  from the first column isnt a border for the entire column but it is applied to each cell, just so you know. Also your second column isnt recognized as a column visually but simply a vertical array of cells. So you would need to elaborate what you need to achieve graphically.

Comment: Good points! I need to change my question. I meant the height of the _CELL_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead on using the Height, I would rather use `VerticalAlignment=Stretch` in this case:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border Background="{Binding Brush}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="40" />
</DataTemplate>
```

this should do the trick

(you might also need a MinHeight in this case, just for safety)

NB: it's a common gotcha that the VerticalAlignment property can also be used to set an equivalent of Height=* in such cases where you want the height to simply fill the space you have, but are not able to bind it to anything. VerticalALignment=Stretch or HorizontalAlignment=Stretch is actually very useful, though not very well known, sadly.

**edit:** if this does not work, you might want to try binding to the parent like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1}}" Background="{Binding Brush}" Width="40" />
</DataTemplate>
```

(Disclaimer: I did not try this in a GridViewColumn's CellTemplate, so don't shoot me if it does not work)

**edit 2:** if nothing above works, try intercalating a Grid or a Panel in your Template, so that it inherits the height an can forward it to the Border. (AFAIK, Grid and Panels do not behave like borders as far as Measure inheritance is concerned):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="{Binding Brush}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="40" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

or:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border Background="{Binding Brush}" Width="40" Height="{Binding ActualHeight ElementName=grid}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I've tried to set VerticalAlignment, but that does not work. I seems like the height is set to 0 because no border is shown. If I use MinHeight then that value is always used.

Comment: arg, It worked in My dataGrid CellTemplate, and I really don't see why this does not work in a GridView. Anyway, see my edit for an other option...

Comment: I will not shoot you! Promise. :) Anyway, it didnt work. I got an error saying that I need to speciafy a type. How can I figure out what type the parent is? I've tried GridViewColumn without luck.

Comment: ah, no idea what type this is, this is why I used the AncestorLEvel, hoping you would not have to provide the type... sorry about that. I'm thinking of a "last chance" option, see my new Edit

Comment: I'd to find out the right anestortype and then bind ActualHeight then I got the desired effect! Thanks alot!

Comment: ah, so what was the type in the end? I'll edit the answer to add it, it case it can help others. (an by the way, you should also accept the answer if it solved your problem, so that others don't waste time trying to find a solution)

Comment: I've already posted the the solution. Check it out! Btw the type was GridViewRowPresenter.

Comment: ah ok, sorry, did not see your answer last time I checked. happy that it helped you find your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

I've finally got it working by specifying the ancestorType to GridViewPresenter, like this.

```
<Border Background="{Binding Brush}" Width="40" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GridViewRowPresenter}}, Path=ActualHeight}" />
```

Comment: Unlike all other approaches to the problem, this worked for me. If I could upvote this further I would.